# SQL - subtraction row

Tags: sql, row, subtraction

I have the following query

```
SELECT VALUE
    ,Source1
    ,Source2
    ,DocNo
FROM myTable
```

it returns the below data:

[image]

I want to calculate the subtraction based on the below condition:

```
for DocNo A1
if(Source1=1 and Source2=0) VALUE 34
if(Source1=1 and Source2=0) VALUE 21
subtraction  two row 34 - 21 = 13
```

Any idea?

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: please tag the DBMS you are using and also look here to improve the question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: also don't post images,take the time to paste them as text,this allows some one to copy your code for testing  as well

Comment: Is the condition right? if(Source1=1 and Source2=0) VALUE 34
if(Source1=1 and Source2=0) VALUE 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, the query below is you want:

```
SELECT Value, Score1, Score2, DocNo
FROM TestTable 
WHERE Score1 = 0

UNION 

SELECT MAX(Value) - MIN(Value) AS Value, 1, 1, DocNo
FROM TestTable 
WHERE Score1 = 1
GROUP BY DocNo
ORDER BY DocNo, Score1
```

<kbd>[`DEMO`](http://rextester.com/EZMG98946)</kbd> for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using QL server 2012 or higher version,you can use LEAD() function.

```
WITH cte_1
AS
(SELECT VALUE, 
        VALUE-LEAD(VALUE) OVER(PARTITION BY DocNo ORDER BY DocNo) Result,
       Source1, 
       Source2,
       LEAD(Source1) OVER(PARTITION BY DocNo ORDER BY DocNo) NxtSource1,
       LEAD(Source2) OVER(PARTITION BY DocNo ORDER BY DocNo) NxtSource2,
       DocNo   
     FROM #myTable)
SELECT Case WHEN (Source1=1 AND NxtSource1=1) AND (Source2=0 AND NxtSource2=1) THEN Result ELSE VALUE END as Value,
       Source1,Source2,DocNo
FROM cte_1
WHERE (Source1<>1 OR source2 <>1)
```

OUTPUT :

[image]

Comment: Window functions are not specific to SQL Server. They are also available in Postgres, Oracle, DB2, Firebird and several other DBMS.

Comment: oh.. ok..  I thought the user forgot to tag the respective database. So SQL tag  alone stands for  window functions .. I have posted answers for some other questions also which does not have a proper  RDMS tag..:) anyway thanks for the information. i will keep in mind.

Comment: The tag `sql` is for questions related to the query language SQL. The term "SQL"  does not denote any special database system. People asking SQL related questions should add a tag for the DBMS they use. They even get a popup telling them that - but unfortunately not everybody reads this or follows that guideline.